# Count the number of fields in each csv record

Tags: code-golf

Imagine a text file where each  csv record may have different numbers of fields.   The task is to write code to output how many fields there are in each record of the file. You can assume there is no header line in the file and can read in from a file or standard input, as you choose.

You can assume a version of [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) for the csv rules which I will explain below for the definition of each line of the file.  Here is a lightly edited version of the relevant part of the spec:

**Definition of the CSV Format**

1. Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
   break (CRLF).  For example:

   ```
   aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
   ```

zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF

2. The last record in the file may or may not have an ending line
   break.  For example:

   ```
   aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
   ```

zzz,yyy,xxx

(Rule 3. does not apply in this challenge)

4. Within each record, there may be one or more
   fields, separated by commas.   Spaces are considered part
   of a field and should not be ignored.
5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes.  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:

   ```
   "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
   ```

zzz,yyy,xxx

6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
   should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:

   ```
   "aaa","b CRLF
   ```

bb","ccc" CRLF
zzz,yyy,xxx

7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
   appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
   another double quote.  For example:

   ```
   "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
   ```

### Example

Input:

```
,"Hello, World!"
"aaa","b""bb","ccc"
zzz,yyy,
"aaa","b 
bb","ccc","fish",""
```

Should give the output:

```
2, 3, 3, 5
```

Your can give the output values in any way you find most convenient.

### Libraries

You can use any library you like.

---

Awesome answers so far but we are missing a command line/bash answer which would be particularly cool.

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>19</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
èJ§3‼}vAà○L>
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8a4a1533137d764185094c3e&i=,%22Hello,+World%21%22%0A%22aaa%22,%22b%22%22bb%22,%22ccc%22%0Azzz,yyy,%0A%22aaa%22,%22b+%0Abb%22,%22ccc%22,%22fish%22,%22%22&a=1&m=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
_'"/    split *all* of standard input by double quote characters
2::     keep only the even numbered elements
|j      split on newlines (implicitly concatenates array of "strings")
m       for each line, execute the rest of the program and output
  ',#^  count the number of commas occurring as substrings, and increment
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=_%27%22%2F++%09split+*all*+of+standard+input+by+double+quote+characters%0A2%3A%3A+++%09keep+only+the+even+numbered+elements%0A%7Cj++++%09split+on+newlines+%28implicitly+concatenates+array+of+%22strings%22%29%0Am+++++%09for+each+line,+execute+the+rest+of+the+program+and+output%0A++%27,%23%5E%09count+the+number+of+commas+occurring+as+substrings,+and+increment&i=,%22Hello,+World%21%22%0A%22aaa%22,%22b%22%22bb%22,%22ccc%22%0Azzz,yyy,%0A%22aaa%22,%22b+%0Abb%22,%22ccc%22,%22fish%22,%22%22&a=1&m=1)

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @Anush: I've added some more information.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
(x=count.fields(stdin(),","))[!is.na(x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcq9CoAgGEbh3auwd1L48A7au4OGaPAnSRCFLEhv3pyazvCcq3fxzjY/6VY@HNEVUW4XkpAEgpTbFIpKWrxy74TliDETX/MV3QQGrfW4DGDMqLUWrLVGtVb6kbMfCT6UcwT9Aw)

Per the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/count.fields.html) of `count.fields`, fields with line breaks get a field count of NA for the initial line, so we filter them out.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES2018), <s>42</s> 59 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/".+?"/sg).split`\n`.map(c=>c.split`,`.length)
```

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/".+?"/sg).split`\n`.map(c=>c.split`,`.length)

console.log(f(
`,"Hello, World!"
"aaa","b""bb","ccc"
zzz,yyy,
"aaa","b 
bb","ccc","fish",""`))
```

Comment: Technically this is ES2018 due to the `s` flag on the regex. Not that it matters that much ;-) And nice use of it, btw!

Comment: This function only appears to work on one record at a time.  I think the problem description requires handling an entire file of multiple records.

Comment: @ETHproductions, good point, will update.

Comment: @recursive, you're right, I misunderstood the inputs.  Now updated, at the loss of many *many* bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṣ”"m2FỴ=”,§‘
```

A port of [recursive's Stax answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166582/53748) - go give credit!

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGuYq5Rq5Pdy9xRbI1Dm0/FHDjP///6urq@soeQBV5esohOcX5aQoKnEpJSYmKukoJekoKenoAImkJCAvOTlZiauqqkqnsrJSB65EgQsuqaOUllmcAaSUgGYCAA)**

#### How?

```
ṣ”"m2FỴ=”,§‘ - Link: list of characters, V
 ”"          - a double quote character = '"'
ṣ            - split (V) at ('"')
   m2        - modulo slice with two (1st, 3rd, 5th, ... elements of that)
     F       - flatten list of lists to a list
      Ỵ      - split at newlines
        ”,   - comma character = ','
       =     - equal? (vectorises)
          §  - sum each
           ‘ - increment (vectorises)
             - (as a full program implicit print)
```

---

Maybe you prefer [`ṣ”"m2ẎỴċ€”,‘`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGuYq5Ro93NX3cPeWI92PmtYABXQeNcz4//@/urq6jpIHUGW@jkJ4flFOiqISl1JiYqKSjlKSjpKSjg6QSEoC8pKTk5W4qqqqdCorK3XgShS44JI6SmmZxRlASgloJgA) - `Ẏ` is tighten and `ċ€` counts the commas in each.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/).10.0, <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```perl
$_=shift;s/"(""|[^"])*"//g;s/^.*$/1+$&=~y:,::/gem;say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcmxDoIwGEXhnafAm8YI/lIYWCDsLs4ORkzBAk2qJZSlxPjoViamLzlnlJPOvWePyg6qm0vLcQA@txr3KAbn/VrqJGY8O7J99XUFFQXv5au0wnnvCWeptaHwaib93CGAEAKEBmia1bZtESzLQs452mYYbJPQKTus4GfGWZm39adLnmRpkv4B)

Explanation:

```perl
$_=shift;          # first command-line arg
s/"(""|[^"])*"//g; # remove quoted fields
s/^.*$/            # replace each line       
  1+$&=~y:,::      # by the number of commas plus 1
/gem;
say                # print
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 63 bytes

```
import csv
def f(s):return map(len,csv.reader(s.split("\n"))
```

Returns the output in an iterable `map` object.

Comment: Using a `lambda` function you can get this down to [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYyxCsMgFEV3v8LeSYtk6VbI3j/okuVpDBGMikpBf946ZTpwz@GmVs8YXuNYt@Hp0jvx8r4oCW@DMuW3ZEu7zaIsJXlXBbYAKSVzV4q58lmMylcOQOFjvY@Kf2P2@wMMRDRXDWg9aYwB672r1pq6JWe3VDhcOSe2@QbGUnahiuchqpTjDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
Length/@ImportString[#,"CSV"]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98nNS@9JEPfwTO3IL@oJLikKDMvPVpZR8k5OEwpVu1/AJBf4pDmoKQTo@SRmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6IYo8QVo5SYmBgDkkmKUQISSWB2cnIyUK6qqkqnsrJSB1mRAheyEiCdllmcAWbEKCn9BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, 101 bytes

```java
s->{for(var p:s.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"","x").split("\n"))System.out.println(p.split(",",-1).length);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##VVBNT8MwDL3zK4xPDUojcaUCiRsXdtmBwzKkNG23jCyNkqyinfrbi9sVJCRb/nrye/ZJdSo/VV@TtipGeFfGXe8AjEt1aJSuYTOXAF1rKtDZNgXjDhBZQd2RnCwmlYyGDTh4hinmL9emDVmnAvinKELtLe15tTZDibtPifsHicjxG5mI3ppEfYeMbfuY6rNoL0l4IknWZf4XwJHnj0zY2h3SkRXjVNyo/aW0RL0qWDSe6YJV5m4Pit3kO6Fpi8S32tqWw0cbbHUviViiUkrOo5JKLMsl13qeDcPA@77n/1HuD6OX2Jh4XBK6an3LOP0A)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                                    // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(var p:s.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"","x") 
                                        //  Replace all words within quotes with an "x"
             .split("\n"))              //  Then split by new-line and loop over them:
    System.out.println(p.split(",",-1)  //   Split the item by comma's
                        .length);}      //   And print the length of this array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
=”"ÄḂżṣ⁷Ż¤ṣ€0,”,Ẉ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/2UcNcpcMtD3c0Hd3zcOfiR43bj@4@tATEalpjoAOU1Hm4q@P/4fajkx7unPH/v46SB1Bfvo5CeH5RToqiEpdSYmKiko5SkpJSUhKQTk5OVuKqqqrSqays1IFLKnDBJXWU0jKLM4CUEgA)

-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan). *duh duh duh...*

Answer (score 0):

## POSIX shell ([ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs) + [usp-engineers-community/Open-usp-tukubai](https://github.com/usp-engineers-community/Open-usp-Tukubai)), 19 bytes

Dependencies are

- [parsrc.sh `Version : 2017-07-18 02:39:39 JST`](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs/blob/ac17529b4951333921ac14a7f201ddc2ecda1fd9/parsrc.sh)
- [count `Version : Fri Oct 21 11:26:06 JST 2011`](https://github.com/usp-engineers-community/Open-usp-Tukubai/blob/25f30c5fb0c315ae8de8c42608a56f68cd99ab6c/COMMANDS/count)

```bash
parsrc.sh|count 1 1
```

### Output format

For each line, the following line is output:

```
<row number> <number of columns>
```

### How it works

`parsrc.sh` is a parser for CSV who converts such text into list of cells and their value.
Open-usp-tukubai's `count` takes a range of field number from parameters and space-separated values to count in such range to summarize.
Here are some comments:

```sh
# raw CSV
parsrc.sh |
# 1: row number 2: column number 3: value where LFs are represented as "\n" while real backslashes as "\\"
count 1 1
# 1: row number 2: number of columns in the row
```

### Example run on Termux

Because Termux is not a completely POSIX-compatible so `command -p getconf PATH` fails, I am dropping the boilerplate to set PATH environment variable so the shell calls completely POSIX-compatible utilities first. Also because I am lazy to prepare Python 2, I am doing with COMMANDS.SH/count.

[image: Example run on Termux but had some modification]